# pandas applying regex to replace values

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have read some pricing data into a pandas dataframe the values appear as:

```
$40,000*
$40000 conditions attached
```

I want to strip it down to just the numeric values.
I know I can loop through and apply regex

```py
[0-9]+
```

to each field then join the resulting list back together but is there a not loopy way?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could remove all the non-digits using `re.sub()`:

```
value = re.sub(r"[^0-9]+", "", value)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/yS7lG7)

Comment: `\D+` will be the smallest :-P

Comment: whats the best way to apply it to the column in the dataframe? so I have df['pricing'] do I just loop row by row?

Comment: @KillerSnail I don't have much experience with pandas, but I think that you should be able to use it like this: `df['pricing'] = re.sub(r"[^0-9]+", "", df['pricing'])`.

Comment: @SabujHassan Smaller doesn't necessarily mean better. `\D` tends to be slower and that's not better at all.

Comment: ok I think I got it for pandas use: df['Pricing'].replace(to_replace='[^0-9]+', value='',inplace==True,regex=True) the .replace method uses re.sub

Comment: @KillerSnail Nice, thanks for letting me know too :)

Comment: caution - stripping all non digit symbols would remove negative sign decimal point, and join together unrelated numbers, e.g. "$8.99 but $2 off with coupon" becomes "8992", "$5.99" becomes "499", "$5" becomes "5".

Comment: @KillerSnail Your solution needs one correction: The double equals (==) after inplace should be replaced by single equals (=)  
    df['Pricing'].replace(to_replace='[^0-9]+', value='',inplace=True,regex=True)

Answer (score 155):

You could use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['$40,000*','$40000 conditions attached'], columns=['P'])
print(df)
#                             P
# 0                    $40,000*
# 1  $40000 conditions attached

df['P'] = df['P'].str.replace(r'\D+', '', regex=True).astype('int')
print(df)
```

yields

```
       P
0  40000
1  40000
```

since `\D` matches any [character that is not a decimal digit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Comment: Any way to do this inPlace?

Answer (score 28):

You could use pandas' replace method; also you may want to keep the thousands separator ',' and the decimal place separator '.'

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['$40,000.32*','$40000 conditions attached'], columns=['pricing'])
df['pricing'].replace(to_replace="\$([0-9,\.]+).*", value=r"\1", regex=True, inplace=True)
print(df)
pricing
0  40,000.32
1      40000
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't need regex for this. This should work:

`df['col'] = df['col'].astype(str).convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)`

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still reading this. I'm working on a similar problem and need to replace an entire column of pandas data using a regex equation I've figured out with re.sub

To apply this on my entire column, here's the code.

```
#add_map is rules of replacement for the strings in pd df.
add_map = dict([
    ("AV", "Avenue"),
    ("BV", "Boulevard"),
    ("BP", "Bypass"), 
    ("BY", "Bypass"),
    ("CL", "Circle"),
    ("DR", "Drive"),
    ("LA", "Lane"),
    ("PY", "Parkway"),
    ("RD", "Road"),
    ("ST", "Street"),
    ("WY", "Way"),
    ("TR", "Trail"),
    
      
])

obj = data_909['Address'].copy() #data_909['Address'] contains the original address'
for k,v in add_map.items(): #based on the rules in the dict
    rule1 = (r"(\b)(%s)(\b)" % k) #replace the k only if they're alone (lookup \
b)
    rule2 = (lambda m: add_map.get(m.group(), m.group())) #found this online, no idea wtf this does but it works
    obj = obj.str.replace(rule1, rule2, regex=True, flags=re.IGNORECASE) #use flags here to avoid the dictionary iteration problem
data_909['Address_n'] = obj #store it!
```

Hope this helps anyone searching for the problem I had. Cheers

Comment: The `rule2 = (lambda...` is used as a callable, therefore in your `obj.str.replace` the regex is passed the match object, i.e. your dictionary key to lookup the value pair to replace. Read [pandas.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and [dict.get()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/get) for more information. If anyone has any clarification on the `m.group()` function please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.replace()` directly by passing the pattern as the `regex=` argument and the replacement value as `value=` argument.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ["$40,000*", "$40000 conditions attached"]})
df['col'] = df['col'].replace(regex=r'\D+', value='')
```

It method performs just as fast as the `str.replace` method (because both are syntactic sugar for a Python loop). However, the advantage of this method over `str.replace` is that it can replace values in multiple columns in one call. For a dataframe of string values, one can use:

```py
df = df.replace(regex=r'\D+', value='')
```

the equivalent syntax using `str.replace` would be:

```py
df = df.apply(lambda col: col.str.replace(r'\D+', '', regex=True))
```