# Remove/replace columns values based on another columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df
col1     col2      col3
 ab       1        prab
 cd       2        cdff
 ef       3        eef
```

I want to remove col1 values from the col3 values

the final data frame should look like<

```
df
col1     col2      col3
 ab       1        pr
 cd       2        ff
 ef       3        e
```

How to do it using pandas in most effective way ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove substring from column based on another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892624/remove-substring-from-column-based-on-another-column)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.apply` with `replace` over `axis=1`:

```
df['col3'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['col3'].replace(x['col1'], ''), axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
  col1  col2 col3
0   ab     1   pr
1   cd     2   ff
2   ef     3    e
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a loop is unavoidable since you have to work with replacing/removing substrings. In that case, list comprehension might come in handy:

```
%%timeit
df.apply(lambda x: x['col3'].replace(x['col1'], ''), axis=1)

# 767 µs ± 24.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

while

```
%%timeit
[a.replace(b,'') for a,b in zip(df['col3'], df['col1'])]

# 24.4 µs ± 3.18 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose df is a matrix :

```py
df = [["ab",1,"prab"],["cd",2,"cdff"],["ef",3,"eef"]]
```

You want to remove the key (col1) in each value (col3) for each row :

```py
for row in df:
  row[2] = row[2].replace(row[0],"")
```

Following this documentation each occurence of col1 is replaced by an empty string: "".