# replace substrings in pandas columns while skipping rows with value: None

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension, nonetype

I stole this from here [Remove/replace columns values based on another columns using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57200908/remove-replace-columns-values-based-on-another-columns-using-pandas?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
[a.replace(b,'') for a,b in zip(df1['asker'], df1['party']) if a != None]
```

I added `if a != None` because it always threw error: **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'**

Here are different solutions to the same problem: replacing substring `df1['party']` within col `asker`

```
df1['new_column'] = df1['asker'].replace(to_replace=r'\b'+df1['party']+r'\b', value='',regex=True)

df1['asker'] = df1.apply(lambda x: x['asker'].replace(x['party'], ''), axis = 1)
```

None of them worked as soon as i added the exception for `None` values

example of `df1` columns `party`

```
[QQQ,
None,
RRR-Fraktion]
```

example of `df1` columns `asker`

```
[Konrad Munch QQQ,
None,
Heiko Baer RRR-Fraktion]
```

Comment: Some problem with solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
[a.replace(b,'') if (a != None) and (b != None) 
                 else a
                 for a,b in zip(df1['asker'], df1['party'])]
```

If need test `NaN`s or `None`s use [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.notna.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"asker": ["Heiko Baer RRR-Fraktion", "a", "b", 
                               np.nan, None, None, np.nan], 
                    "party": ['RRR-Fraktion', None, np.nan, 'a', 's', None, np.nan]})
    
df1['asker'] = [a.replace(b,'') if pd.notna(a) and pd.notna(b) 
                                else a 
                                for a,b in zip(df1['asker'], df1['party'])]
print (df1)
         asker         party
0  Heiko Baer   RRR-Fraktion
1            a          None
2            b           NaN
3          NaN             a
4         None             s
5         None          None
6          NaN           NaN
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I had something like this in mind. It doesent remove the substring of `party` from the `asker` thouhg. I does nothing. I just tested your second suggestion. It doesent do anything at all, unfortunately. I cannot explain why

Comment: @id345678 - Can you be more specific?

Comment: I dont know how to be more specific. I could give you an example maybe?

Comment: @id345678 - added to sample data in answer.  `Konrad Munch QQQ` is not substring in `Fraktion der QQQ` so no replacement, so not added to sample data