# insert anchor tags using python in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, html, pandas

I have a list of urls and a list of descriptions in separate columns in a pandas dataframe. I'm trying to figure out a way to use python to insert an anchor tag with a link in the first few words of the description.

I have:

```
df.description[0]
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation"

df.link[0]
https://www.google.com
```

Desired output:

```
df.complete[0]
<a href="https://www.google.com"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
```

The text from the description column varies in length. I'm trying to make sure the hyperlink ends on the last character of a word - the number of words wrapped in the anchor tag don't matter.

Comment: In you case, think you can do that with a single string and a single link, put that in a function, then `df['description'] = df.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x.description, x.link), axis=1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer:

```
df["short_description"] = df["description"].apply(lambda s: shorten(s, width=20, placeholder=""))
df['remaining_desc'] = df.apply(lambda row : row['description'].replace(str(row['short_description']), ''), axis=1)
df['remaining_desc']

df["description_link"] = '<a href="' + df["story_link"] + '">' + df["short_description"] + "</a>" + df["remaining_desc"]
df['description_link']
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`textwrap.shorten`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.shorten) and string manipulation. Try something like this:

```py
from textwrap import shorten

# Change 20 to any value that makes sense
df["short_description"] = df["description"].apply(lambda s: shorten(s, width=20, placeholder=""))

df["description_link"] = (
    # Create the start of the anchor tag
    '<a href="' + df["link"] + '">'

    # Add in the short description text
    df["short_description"]

    # Close the anchor tag
    + "</a>"

    # Append the rest of the description
    + df["description"].str[df["short_description"].str.len:]
)
```

Comment: This got close, but it ultimately returned a list of `NaN`. It did set me down the right path though. I took part of your code and meshed it with this to get the desired result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892624/remove-substring-from-column-based-on-another-column