# Replacing pandas column with a subset of itself through regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have data streaming in the following format:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
data ="""\
ANI/IP
sip:5554447777@10.94.2.15
sip:10.66.7.34@6665554444
sip:3337775555@10.94.2.11
"""
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(data),sep='\s+',dtype='str')
```

What I would like to do is replace the column content with just the phone number part of the string above. I tried the suggestions from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588316/pandas-applying-regex-to-replace-values) like so:

```
df['ANI/IP'] = df['ANI/IP'].str.replace(r'\d{10}', '').astype('str')
print(df)
```

However, this results in:

```
.....print(df)
            ANI/IP
0  sip:@10.94.2.15
1  sip:@10.66.7.34
2  sip:@10.94.2.11
```

I need the phone numbers, so how do I achieve this? :

```
  ANI/IP
0 5554447777
1 6665554444
2 3337775555
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex `\d{10}` searches for substring of digits precisely 10 characters long.

```
df['ANI/IP'] = df['ANI/IP'].str.replace(r'\d{10}', '').astype('str')
```

This removes the numbers!
*Note: You shouldn't do astype str (it's not needed and there is no str dtype in pandas).*

You want to [*extract*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html) these phone numbers:

```
In [11]: df["ANI/IP"].str.extract(r'(\d{10})')  # before overwriting!
Out[11]:
0    5554447777
1    6665554444
2    3337775555
Name: ANI/IP, dtype: object
```

Set this as another column and you're away:

```
In [12]: df["phone_number"] = df["ANI/IP"].str.extract(r'(\d{10})')
```

Comment: That was quick as usual  =)

Comment: Thank you @Andy Hayden. My Python fundamentals are clearly weak! It's been a month since I switched from SAS/R to Python!

Comment: I prefer my typing [70s style](http://houseofthedead.wikia.com/wiki/The_Typing_of_the_Dead_Overkill)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract` to extract

```
In [10]: df['ANI/IP'].str.extract("(\d{10})")
Out[10]:
0    5554447777
1    6665554444
2    3337775555
Name: ANI/IP, dtype: object
```