# How to extract only the numerical part of the columns in this table? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-datareader

I am editing a CSV file in Python, I have deleted some columns, created an index and filtered. But I have not been able to extract the numerical part of the columas. How can I extract only the numerical information from the columns?

Extract only the numeric part of the column data. example:

MarketTime = 11: 18: 26.549

The whole column should be like this:

11: 18: 26,549

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/TECNOLOGIA/datos.csv',names=['LocalTime', 'Message', 'MarketTime', 'Symbol', 'Type', 'Price', 'Size', 'Source','Condition','Tick','Mmid','SubMarketId','Date'],
                 usecols=['Type','MarketTime','Price'],index_col='Type')
df=(df.loc['Type=0'])
print (df)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find numeric columns in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039626/how-do-i-find-numeric-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: Please include the data in the question, not as some image that might disappear in the future.

Comment: we're not code writing service. Please also include what you tried and where you got stuck. Also, include the data array so that we can help you better

Comment: @Aiven: Nope, that isn't it.

Comment: MarketTime           Price
Type                                           
Type=0  MarketTime=11:18:26.549  Price=112.8300
Type=0  MarketTime=11:18:28.792  Price=112.8300
Type=0  MarketTime=11:18:28.792  Price=112.8400
Type=0  MarketTime=11:18:28.792  Price=112.8300
Type=0  MarketTime=11:18:45.798  Price=112.8500
Type=0  MarketTime=11:18:45.799  Price=112.8500
Type=0  MarketTime=11:18:45.880  Price=112.8400

Comment: import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/TECNOLOGIA/datos.csv',names=['LocalTime', 'Message', 'MarketTime', 'Symbol', 'Type', 'Price', 'Size', 'Source','Condition','Tick','Mmid','SubMarketId','Date'],
                 usecols=['Type','MarketTime','Price'],index_col='Type')
df=(df.loc['Type=0'])
print (df)

Comment: This is the part of the code that I have written, but I can not eliminate the numerical part of the columns.

I apologize, it's the first time I joined this forum.

Comment: Please add your data as _text_ in your question. Pictures (or links of pictures) do not make it easy for us to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting the Regex/Pandas StringMethods answer given at [pandas applying regex to replace values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588316/pandas-applying-regex-to-replace-values), you will have something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['MarketTime=11:18:28.792','MarketTime=11:18:28.792'], columns=['MarketTime'])

df['MarketTime'] = df['MarketTime'].str.extract(r'([\d:,.]+)')
print(df)
```

Comment: And please clean up and format your original question, removing the image links.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'm trying to work on all the values ​​in the column. Is it possible to apply it to the whole column?

Comment: Umm it IS applying the extraction to the whole column, what are you seeing?