# Detect exponential value in a dataframe and replace with 10000

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe

```
value 
5
5.67E+54
10
1.04E+26
```

My expected output is

```
value 
5
10000
10
10000
```

I would like to detect exponential value in a dataframe and replace with 10000. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas applying regex to replace values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588316/pandas-applying-regex-to-replace-values)

Comment: `df['value'] = df['value'].str.replace(r'.*E\+.*', '10000', regex=True).astype(int)`