# Python pandas replace abc-1 to abc-01 in a column

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace, regexp-replace

I am using python pandas and here is the dataframe

| sl.no | data_col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 321 | abc-1 |
| 324 | abc-2 |
| 326 | abc-3 |
| 328 | abc-4 |
| 330 | abc-5 |
| 330 | abc-12 |
| 331 | xyz-1 |

Want to replace abc-single digit with abc-01, abc-02, abc-03, data other than start with abc should remains same

| sl.no | data_col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 321 | abc-01 |
| 324 | abc-02 |
| 326 | abc-03 |
| 328 | abc-04 |
| 330 | abc-05 |
| 330 | abc-12 |
| 331 | xyz-1 |

I am new to python need some inputs using df.replace() or any short method

Comment: Maybe your answer not this question? ( how to use regex and replace )  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588316/pandas-applying-regex-to-replace-values)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with a backreference to the capturing group and have it be preceded by `0` (see also: [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)):

```
data = {'sl.no': {0: 321, 1: 324, 2: 326, 3: 328, 4: 330, 5: 330, 6: 331}, 
        'data_col1': {0: 'abc-1', 1: 'abc-2', 2: 'abc-3', 3: 'abc-4', 
                      4: 'abc-5', 5: 'abc-12', 6: 'xyz-1'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['data_col1'] = df['data_col1'].str.replace(r'(?<=abc-)(\d)$',r'0\1', regex=True)

df

   sl.no data_col1
0    321    abc-01
1    324    abc-02
2    326    abc-03
3    328    abc-04
4    330    abc-05
5    330    abc-12
6    331     xyz-1
```

For an explanation of the patterns, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/e1uolR/3).

Alternatively, as mentioned by [@mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76718181/python-pandas-replace-abc-1-to-abc-01-in-a-column/76718258#comment135255282_76718258) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76718181/python-pandas-replace-abc-1-to-abc-01-in-a-column/76718258#comment135255282_76718258), you could pass a function to `repl` and apply [`str.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill):

```
df['data_col1'] = df['data_col1'].str.replace(r'(?<=abc-)(\d+)$', 
                                              lambda x: x.group().zfill(2), 
                                              regex=True)
```

A more labored alternative: use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`Series.str.zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) and do something like this:

```
tmp = df['data_col1'].str.split('-', expand=True)
df['data_col1'] = tmp[0] + '-' + np.where(tmp[0].eq('abc'), tmp[1].str.zfill(2), tmp[1])
```

Comment: Both didnt work

for the first solution  instead of abc-01 output is just 01

Comment: Updated the answer after the update of your Q. Initially, you were showing *only* `abc-` like values, that makes a difference. If it still doesn't work on your set, could you add your original `df` in the form of a dict using `df.to_dict()`?

Comment: you could also apply `zfill` in `str.replace` with a function as replacement ;)